# Estou validando um campo de cpf e preciso fazer uma verificação no banco de dados se este cpf ja foi cadastrado se ja trazer a mensagem ao usuário

Tags: c#, jquery-validate

```
//verifica cpf válido
jQuery.validator.addMethod("verificaCPF", function (value, element) {
    // tamanho do cpf
    if (value.length < 11) return false;
    // retira pontos, virgulas e traços
    value = value.replace('.', '');
    value = value.replace('.', '');
    cpf = value.replace('-', '');
    //  calcular cpf válido
    while (cpf.length < 11) cpf = "0" + cpf;
    var expReg = /^0+$|^1+$|^2+$|^3+$|^4+$|^5+$|^6+$|^7+$|^8+$|^9+$/;
    var a = [];
    var b = new Number;
    var c = 11;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        a[i] = cpf.charAt(i);
        if (i < 9) b += (a[i] * --c);
    }
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[9] = 0 } else { a[9] = 11 - x }
    b = 0;
    c = 11;
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) b += (a[y] * c--);
    if ((x = b % 11) < 2) { a[10] = 0; } else { a[10] = 11 - x; }
    if ((cpf.charAt(9) != a[9]) || (cpf.charAt(10) != a[10]) || cpf.match(expReg)) return false;
    return true;

}, STRINGS.cpfInvalido);
```

Comment: **Junior**, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/334145/edit) sua pergunta e esclareça sua dúvida ou problema. Vejo que já faz um tempo que é membro do site, é importante ler o [tour] para saber como ele funciona e também caso necessite de ajuda sobre como utilizar as ferramentas do mesmo, acesse a [help].

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado

Comment: Então você vai ter que fazer uma requisição para servidor e fazer essa verificação lá, depois retornar a mensagem.

Answer (score 0):

É possível alterar a estrutura do banco?

Porque acredito que a melhor forma de validar isso é tornando o campo CPF único (https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_unique.asp), assim, ao tentar inserir um CPF igual, o banco vai retornar uma mensagem e não vai inserir o registro.